# How to bind multiple CommandParameter from two sources (Datagrid and TreeView) in DataGrid.ContextMenu MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, treeview

I'm trying to create DataGrid.ContextMenu where my MenuItem will contains multiple CommandParameter. I have similar solution assigned into Button:

```
 <GroupBox Header="Tree action" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Button Margin="1,4,0,0" Width="150" Content="Add elements to tree" Command="{Binding Path=AddArticlesToSelectedBranch}">
                            <Button.CommandParameter>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource XAMLDataConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="SelectedItems" ElementName="AllArticles"/>
                                    <Binding Path="SelectedItems" ElementName="NotAssignedArticles"/>
                                    <Binding Path="SelectedItems" ElementName="SelectedBranchArticles"/>
                                    <Binding Path="SelectedItem" ElementName="MainTreeView"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Button.CommandParameter>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Margin="0,4,0,0" Width="150" Content="Get articles" Command="{Binding Path=GetArticlesCommand}" />
                        <Button Margin="0,4,0,0" Width="150" Content="Generate prices" Command="{Binding Path=SaveChangesCommand}" Style="{StaticResource ChangePriceButton}" />
                        <Button Margin="0,4,0,0" Width="150" Content="Clear filters" Command="{Binding Path=ClearFiltersCommand}" Style="{StaticResource ChangePriceButton}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </GroupBox>
```

Unfortunately this solution works perfectly only in this Button and doesn't work with DataGrid.ContextMenu.MenuItem.

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="AllArticles" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                              AlternatingRowBackground="LightCyan" 
                              CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                              Background="White" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding AllArticles}">

                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Prefix" Binding="{Binding Prefix}" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Index" Binding="{Binding Index}" Width="2*" IsReadOnly="True" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="7*" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Base price" Binding="{Binding Price}" Width="2*" IsReadOnly="True">
                                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                        <Style>
                                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
                                        </Style>
                                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                </DataGridTextColumn>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGrid.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,2"/>
                                </Style>

                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="blue" />
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGrid.Resources>
                            <!-- ContextMenu-->
                            <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Add to tree" Command="{Binding Path=AddArticlesToSelectedBranch}">
                                        <MenuItem.CommandParameter>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource XAMLDataConverter}">
                                                <Binding Path="SelectedItems" ElementName="AllArticles"/>
                                                <Binding Path="SelectedItems" ElementName="NotAssignedArticles"/>
                                                <Binding Path="SelectedItems" ElementName="SelectedBranchArticles"/>
                                                <Binding Path="SelectedItem" ElementName="MainTreeView"/>
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </MenuItem.CommandParameter>
                                    </MenuItem>
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                        </DataGrid>
```

Parameters AllArticles, NotAssignedArticles and SelectedBranchArticles are selected items of this DataGrid (they are ObservableCollection on which DataGrid is based on. They are 3, because this DataGrid contains 3 separate Tabs).

Last parameter called "MainTreeView" is taken from TreeView (Selected Item)

Under phase "doesn't work" I meant, code is compiled, application didn't crush but after click, my method:

```
 private void AddArticlesToBranch(object obj)
    { 
// do some stuff
}
```

receives in paramether obj 4 objects of type DependencyProperty.UnsetValue.

As I mentioned before, this solution is also implemented inside one Button and in this case it works fine.

### UPDATE

I found a work around for my issue - I added additional bool property into my TreeView model and then added below code to XAML:

```
 <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
     <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsCheckedInMenu, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
   </Style>
 </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

and now I'm able to find selected item using LINQ in ViewModel.

Comment: Is there are reason you are using a `DataGrid.ContextMenu` with only one item in it instead of a `Button` inside of a cell? Might also solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, it is. The reason why I'm using context menu is fact, that it allows me to selected multiple items and do action on them. Even if I use button instead of context menu it will probably not work - during my searching process somewhere I read that the main problem here is fact, that from DataGird (starting point) I don't have an access into data storage in TreeView.